# iOS UICollectionView Drag-N-Drop

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

I use UICollectionViewDragDelegate & UICollectionViewDropDelegate to implement Drag-N-Drop functionality for my collectionView. However, I don't know how I can detect the following actions:

1. If the user just lifts the photo but doesn't move, and then release.
2. If the user drags the cell & move but still drop at the original position.

In summary, I just found that if the destination position is the same as the original position, the function performDropWithCoordinator will not be called. So I don't know how to check if the new position is the same as the original position.

Comment: This is not trivial - anyhow, were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

To detect when a drag starts, implement this in the collection view controller

```
- (BOOL) collectionView: ( UICollectionView * ) collectionView
 canMoveItemAtIndexPath: ( NSIndexPath      * ) indexPath
```

This will fire when the drag begins. Then, to detect when it ends, you need to subclass the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and implement this

```
// ZZZ!!!
- ( UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext * ) invalidationContextForEndingInteractiveMovementOfItemsToFinalIndexPaths:( NSArray < NSIndexPath * > * ) indexPaths
                                                       previousIndexPaths:( NSArray < NSIndexPath * > * ) previousIndexPaths
                                                    movementCancelled:( BOOL                        ) movementCancelled
```

BUT be careful. If the item was moved then the usual

```
// XXX!!!
- (void) collectionView:( UICollectionView * ) collectionView
    moveItemAtIndexPath:( NSIndexPath      * ) sourceIndexPath
        toIndexPath:( NSIndexPath      * ) destinationIndexPath
```

would have been called BEFORE this is called. If the item was not moved but just dropped in place, then XXX!!! above will not be called but ZZZ!!! will still be called, so you need to implement some logic to get it working properly.

I suggest you set the source index path when the drag starts and whenever it is handled you set it to nil. Then you can check for that before you apply the move.

For me it sometimes happens when an item is dragged to an adjacent cell (that the XXX is not called, only ZZZ) but I suspect that is due to the way in which I handle other aspects of the drag.

**EDIT**

Just to make it clear - ZZZ is always called last. XXX is not always called but if it is, it is called before ZZZ. So maybe XXX then ZZZ tells you the drag ended.

PS : I did not use drop delegate (mine is iOS 10 compatible) but I think you'd be able to transfer this to your drop-delegate-enabled solution.

Answer (score 0):

this is my *second* answer.

The previous one was really for iOS 10, this one is a bit more modern even if it is incomplete.

Take a look at `dragStateDidChange`. That message is send to the `UICollectionViewCell` and so you won't find it in either the drag- or drop delegates that you use, but you might be able to accomplish what you wish there.

Then, another comment, in the drop delegate, the message `collectionView:dropSessionDidUpdate:withDestinationIndexPath:` gives you a destination path but you typically need to translate that with something like

```
NSIndexPath * dst = [collectionView presentationIndexPathForDataSourceIndexPath:destinationIndexPath];
```

to get the real destination, especially if you want to check that it is different from the original destination path.